# Windows 7 MinGW compilation error using Boost ASIO

Tags: compilation, mingw, boost-asio

Having trouble compiling the following C++ code on Windows 7:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void handler1(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
  std::cout << "5 s." << std::endl;
}

void handler2(const boost::system::error_code &ec)
{
  std::cout << "10 s." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  timer1.async_wait(handler1);
  boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2(io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(10));
  timer2.async_wait(handler2);
  io_service.run();
}
```

I have MinGW installed (gcc 4.8.1) in `c:\mingw` with my `PATH` set up correctly.  I have downloaded boost and declared environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` to be the path where it resides.  I have gone through the `bootstrap` and `b2` procedure for boost.  I now try and compile:

```
c:\path\to\sandbox> g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -o main main.cpp
```

Gives a bunch of **`error: '::UnregisterWaitEx' has not been declared`** errors

I then search a bit and see I may need to link **`boost_system`**.  So:

```
c:\path\to\sandbox> g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -lboost_system -o main main.cpp
```

Same errors.  Thought I'd try specify library path.  Did a search for boost_system and found static libs (libboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55.a) in `%BOOST_ROOT%/stage/lib`. So

```
c:\path\to\sandbox> g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%/stage/lib -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55 -o main main.cpp
```

Same errors.  So I search again and see others suggesting appending a **`-D-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601`**. So

```
c:\path\to\sandbox> g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%/stage/lib -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55 -o main main.cpp -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
```

**And the inevitable errors:**

```
c:\mingw\include\mswsock.h:125:20: error: 'WSAPOLLFD' was not declared in this scope
 int WSAAPI WSAPoll(WSAPOLLFD, ULONG, INT);
                ^
c:\mingw\include\mswsock.h:125:36: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token
 int WSAAPI WSAPoll(WSAPOLLFD, ULONG, INT);
                                ^
c:\mingw\include\mswsock.h:125:41: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
 int WSAAPI WSAPoll(WSAPOLLFD, ULONG, INT);
                                     ^
c:\mingw\include\mswsock.h:125:41: error: expression list treated as compound     expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to link to winsock for windows, add: -lwsock32 -lws2_32 to remove the "inevitable errors"

Comment: Thanks but still getting errors. `g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%/stage/lib -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55 -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -o main main.cpp -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` gives a bunch of `undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'` errors.  Suggests linker is having trouble with `boost_system` but I don't really know what.

Comment: Oh, and I should mention I had to patch `winsock2.h` as specified here - http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1980/.  Otherwise I was still getting those `UnregisterWaitEx` errors.

Comment: FYI I've just built and run your code on my system; it works fine. However, my link order is: `-L%BOOST_ROOT%/stage/lib -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-d`...

Comment: Thanks but still no joy.  I reinstalled mingw using the graphical tool as opposed to unpacking the packages manually, and I've rebuilt boost 1.55 doing `bootstrap.bat mingw` then `b2 toolset=gcc`.  Then I tried again: `g++ -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-1_55 -o boosttest boosttest.cpp -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601` in the order you suggested. Still seeing `undefined reference to boost::system::generic_category()` error.  Hmm I don't know, I'll have another search and see if anyone else if having similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went ahead and rebuilt Boost again with `b2 toolset=gcc --build-type=complete`. Same thing happened.  Finally, after all that, it turned out all I needed was to put the linking at the end of the command:

```
C:\path\to\sandbox> g++ -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -I%BOOST_ROOT% -L%BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib -o boosttest boosttest.cpp -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_55

C:\path\to\sandbox> boosttest.exe
5 s.
10 s.
```

The `-D_WIN32_WINNT` was still necessary and, for anyone who has skipped the other comments, I had to patch `winsock.h` as detailed http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1980/.  And remember to put `%BOOST_ROOT%\stage\lib` in your `PATH` so Windows can find the dll at runtime.

Arduous