# How to fix undefined reference to `GetAcceptExSockaddrs' (Boost.Asio) in CLion

Tags: c++, boost, clion

I have included Boost 1.61.0. My C++ project had [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767653/how-to-fix-undefined-reference-to-imp-wsacleanup-boost-asio-in-clion), I added `target_link_libraries(WsServer ws2_32)` and fixed it. Then, another error appeared. The code: [WebSocket++ examples: simple_broadcast_server.cpp](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/simple_broadcast_server/simple_broadcast_server.cpp) . How I can fix it?

Console:

```
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::asio::detail::socket_ops::complete_iocp_accept(unsigned long long, void*, unsigned long, sockaddr*, unsigned long long*, unsigned long long, boost::system::error_code&)':
C:/MinGW/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/socket_ops.ipp:199: undefined reference to `GetAcceptExSockaddrs'
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::start_accept_op(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type&, bool, boost::asio::detail::socket_holder&, int, int, int, void*, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*)':
C:/MinGW/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:495: undefined reference to `AcceptEx'
CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir/objects.a(main.cpp.obj): In function `boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::restart_accept_op(unsigned long long, boost::asio::detail::socket_holder&, int, int, int, void*, unsigned long, boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_operation*)':
C:/MinGW/include/boost/asio/detail/impl/win_iocp_socket_service_base.ipp:520: undefined reference to `AcceptEx'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\WsServer.dir\build.make:99: WsServer.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:67: CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:79: CMakeFiles/WsServer.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: WsServer] Error 2
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(WsServer)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=gnu++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp)

include_directories(C:/Users/Marczak/CPPLibs)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(WsServer ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(WsServer ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

target_link_libraries(WsServer ws2_32)
```

Comment: FYI, `AcceptEx()` or `GetAcceptExSockaddrs()` are *Microsoft-specific extensions* to WinSock and thus cannot be *statically* linked to at compile-time, per the WinSock documentation: "*The function pointer for the AcceptEx [and GetAcceptExSockaddrs] function[s] **must be obtained at run time by making a call to the `WSAIoctl` function with the `SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER` opcode specified*". I would expect boost to handle that internally.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems that you have to add `wsock32` to link libraries, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22729822/windows-7-mingw-compilation-error-using-boost-asio) post.

Comment: What do you mean? I added `link_libraries(ws2_32)` too, but got same error.

Comment: Updated main post. Take a look for CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Is ws2_32 different than wsock32?

Comment: Works! Thanks again.

Comment: See [Winsock2.h vs winsock2.h and wsock32.lib vs ws2_32.lib](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31644112/65863)

Comment: Thank you! 
I added this to my CMakeLists.txt and it compiled!
`target_link_libraries( ${PROJECT_NAME} -lws2_32 -lwsock32 )`